# Swap/Dump session data using passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, redis, mean-stack, passport.js

I am using Passport for my MEAN stack-based app, that makes use of several APIs that require several OAuth tokens. Because logging in and out causes too much overhead, I am considering to put serialized session data in a Redis store then swap back and forth between existing sessions.

So my question is, is there a way to programmatically extract and/or replace passport data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try storing the information in MongoDB by using serializeUser() and get it back using deserializeUser()?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It would have solved my problem indeed - although I would find something like Redis to be a more suitable candidate for that use case. I actually ended up using client-side libraries for alternate oAuth sessions, while preserving a very single "main" server session.